# How to read from stdin each byte and process them in c#

Tags: c#, byte, stdin

I have a problem to reading each byte goes to stdin in c# from another application.

The code is simple:

```
Stream instrm=Console.OpenStandardInput();
while(true){
   int b=instrm.ReadByte();
   Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

How I think it should work:
When on instrm will be a byte - application will close. But when I fire bytes to application, nothing happening.
Am I doing it in wrong way, or what? any clues...

Comment: Your question says "stdin in c# from another application" but code shows re-opening your own standard input... Which one is correct?

Comment: I have two application one fires bytes to another using stdin.
The code above is example of the receiver (written on c#)
My guess was to open stdin stream and listening it for data

Comment: That code looks ok to me (also I never tried that)... `Console.ReadXXXX` should be enough for reading (I personally would not try to read non-text this way)... But please show the code for sender as there some chance you are not really sending anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another solution for me:
compile project using .net version 3.5 or lower, in that case everything starts work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            while(true) {
               var k = Console.ReadKey();
               Environment.Exit(1);
               }
            }
```

C# is Unicode based and while streams are generally encoded UTF-8 you still don't want to get in the habit of reading bytes.  Also the other Console read methods don't get any data until a newline is entered (in case you want to backup).

I wonder if what you really want to use is a Pipe ?

Comment: When I using pipes, also nothig happends... Maby I doing it in wrong way.. the logic is the same - create anonymousPipeServerStream and start reading byte from that server in while(true)

Comment: Retrying Pipes as in MSDN example. Its start Working! =) Thanks